# Odoo13: Customize Gantt view Renderer / GanttRow

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-13

In odoo v13, for my custom module: "event_salles_zsb", i want to customize the Ganttview for my custom model, to add custom content (color for gantt cells...). Using js, I have prototyped the GanttView, its GanttRenderer and its GanttRow...js-Customizations of my GanttModel work fine ("SallesGanttModel" not shown here)... but any change in my custom GanttRow xml-template  "SallesGanttRow"(linked with the js-prototype : SallesGanttRow) has no effect.

**static/src/js/salles_gantt_view.js:**

```js
odoo.define('event_salles_zsb.SallesGanttView', function (require) {
'use strict';
var GanttView = require('web_gantt.GanttView');
var GanttController = require('web_gantt.GanttController');
//var GanttRenderer = require('web_gantt.GanttRenderer');
var SallesGanttRenderer = require('event_salles_zsb.SallesGanttRenderer');
var SallesGanttModel = require('event_salles_zsb.SallesGanttModel');

var view_registry = require('web.view_registry');

var SallesGanttView = GanttView.extend({
    config: _.extend({}, GanttView.prototype.config, {
        Model: SallesGanttModel,
        Controller: GanttController,
        Renderer: SallesGanttRenderer,
    }),
});

view_registry.add('salles_gantt', SallesGanttView);
return SallesGanttView;
});
```

**static/src/js/salles_gantt_renderer.js:**

```js
odoo.define('event_salles_zsb.SallesGanttRenderer', function (require) {
    'use strict';
    const GanttRenderer = require('web_gantt.GanttRenderer');
    const SallesGanttRow = require('event_salles_zsb.SallesGanttRow');

    const SallesGanttRenderer = GanttRenderer.extend({
        config: Object.assign({}, GanttRenderer.prototype.config, {
            GanttRow: SallesGanttRow
        }),
    });

    return SallesGanttRenderer;
});
```

**static/src/js/salles_gantt_row.js**

```js
odoo.define('event_salles_zsb.SallesGanttRow', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    const GanttRow = require('web_gantt.GanttRow');

    const SallesGanttRow = GanttRow.extend({
        template: 'SallesGanttView.Row',

    });
    return SallesGanttRow;
});
```

**static/src/xml/cust_gantt_content.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">


<t t-name="SallesGanttView.Row" t-extend="GanttView.Row">
       <t t-jquery="*.o_gantt_pill" t-operation="append">
            <div>
            <strong>MY CUSTOM HTML CONTENT</strong>
            </div>
        </t>
</t>


</templates>
```

****manifest**.py**

```py
{
    'name': "event_salles_zsb",
    'summary': """book salles for events""",
    
    'category': 'Event',
    'version': '13.0.2.0.28',
    'depends': ['website_event','web_gantt','event_type_zsb'],
    'data': [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/event_salles_views.xml',
        'views/assets.xml',
    ],
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/cust_gantt_content.xml',
        
    ],
}
```

**views/assets.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend" name="event_salles_zsb_backend_assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/event_salles_zsb/static/src/js/salles_gantt_model.js" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/event_salles_zsb/static/src/js/salles_gantt_view.js" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/event_salles_zsb/static/src/js/salles_gantt_row.js" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/event_salles_zsb/static/src/js/salles_gantt_renderer.js" />
            <!--script type="text/javascript" src="/event_salles_zsb/static/src/js/salles_gantt_controller.js" /-->
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

Comment: yeah, seems to be a hard issue to figure out how to just enter to start looking anything. Very time consuming I belive